# Optical activity of cis coordination compounds

Tags: stereochemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers, symmetry, cis-trans-isomerism

I came across a statement saying,

> "Consider a **Octahedral** coordination compound of type [MA2X2]. Then,
>   if the compound is in a cis form, it shows optical activity as there
>   is no plane of symmetry and hence is non-superimposable on its mirror
>   image. On the other hand, a trans form is symmetric and superimposable
>   on its mirror image and so is optically inactive."
>   [image]

I do not see why the cis form is not superimposable on its mirror image. If all the ligands lie on the same plane, then isn't there a line of symmetry passing diagonally? Does that not make it superimposable on its mirror image?

Comment: [$\ce{[CoCl2(en)2]+}$ isn't square planar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis-Dichlorobis(ethylenediamine)cobalt(III)_chloride). Please add a reference for the quoted part.

Comment: Point 1. The compound is not planar(it is octahedral). Point 2. Line/Axis of symmetry doesn't affect chirality. Only POS,COS,alternating Axis of symmetry does. But for any planar molecule, molecular plane is itself a plane of symmetry so planar compounds are always achiral

Comment: ah duly noted. Turns out I got the structures messed up. I will edit my question for future viewers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not always as easy to see from a standard octahedral depiction. Optical activity in octahedral complexes can be understood better, if you draw the octahedron as looking onto a triangular face rather than along an edge; this results in a hexagonal arrangement of ligands around the central atom with ligands alternately pointing into and out of the paper plane.

If we do that with $\ce{[Co(en)2Cl2]}$, we get the following two enantiomers which you cannot convert into each other:

[image: both enantiomers of the [Co(en)2Cl2] complex]

The complex is chiral because the $\ce{en}$ ligands necessarily cross the paper plane and can do so either in a right-turn screw motion or in a left-turn screw motion.